# Reset default docker context

Tags: docker

I inadvertedly tied docker default to a remote kubernetes endpoint. How can I reset these values:

```
NAME                TYPE                DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT                                   KUBERNETES ENDPOINT                                                              ORCHESTRATOR
default             moby                Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   unix:///var/run/docker.sock                       https://*.eks.amazonaws.com (dev)   swarm
desktop-linux *     moby
```

I have tried resetting docker to factory defaults and updating it directly but that didn't work.

```
docker context update default --kubernetes Host=https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/     
"default" is a reserved context name
```

Comment: Shouldn't matter anymore since it's deprecated? https://docs.docker.com/engine/deprecated/#kubernetes-stack-and-context-support